# How to remove Adorner of a TextBox if the Parent Grid / Panel is not visible anymore

Tags: c#, wpf, adorner

I have "made my own" TextBox with some Adorners.

The first Adorner will display the "Title" in it if .Text value is empty.

The second will highlight the border red if the input is wrong..

Works well, but now i have the case that MyTextBox is within a Grid which will be invisible from start up .. instead of a "create new dialog" i make this grid visible as an "popup" within the mainwindow .. works well too!

but if i collapse this Grid, the adorner will stay there ..

how can the TextBox see that it's parent panel is not visible anymore??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you iterate through the VisualTree using the [VisualTreeHelper.getParent()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.media.visualtreehelper.getparent(v=vs.110).aspx)-Method.

If you found your Grid, listen to it´s IsVisibleChanged-Event.

Greetigns

Comment: had this idea too, but what if its the third "panel" which will be collapsed .. workaround is just now to search all "panels" .. not really nice, but will work ..

Comment: Ok, and whats about the IsVisible-Property of your TextBox? I think it should return false if the textbox is not rendered.

Comment: i thought i have tried it, but seems that i did not .. =/ sorry! was so simple .. ! thank you :)